# Interpolate in YAML

Tags: perl, anchor, yaml, interpolation

I am using Perl as my scripting language and reading YAML config. files. There's a few fields (like memory address) which are used often and are relative to the base field. Is it possible to interpolate an anchored value and perform any operation on it, within the YAML file? I am using YAML::XS as the parser module in Perl.

For example, in file.cfg.yml

```
%YAML 1.1
---
- base: &base 10001000
- reg:
    - abc: *base + 4
...
```

Is it possible to perform any operation on bin, oct or hex values?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can serialise the operations as code. Deserialising code is a really stupid idea if you cannot control the input. Take [CVE-2013-0156](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=CVE-2013-0156) and [CVE-2013-0333](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=CVE-2013-0333) to heart.

```
use YAML::XS qw(Dump);
$YAML::XS::UseCode = 1; # DANGER DANGER OMG WHYYYY ARE YOU DOING THIS ARE YOU NUTS OR WHAT

my $base = 10001000;
my $data = [
    {
        base => $base
    },
];
push @{ $data }, {
    reg => [
        {
            abc => sub { $data->[0]{base} + 4 },
        }
    ]
};

print Dump $d;
__END__
---
- base: 10001000
- reg:
- abc: !!perl/code |-
    {
        $$data[0]{'base'} + 4;
    }
```

Comment: Can you do it the other way round? Define it in some way in the file and `eval` in the code?